# How do you check if all the values in a column in a dataframe exist in another column in another dataframe using Vaex?

Tags: python, vaex

I have a dataframe with 160,000 rows and I need to know if these values exist in another column in another different dataframe that has over 7 million rows using Vaex.

I have tried doing this in pandas but it takes way too long to run.

Once I run this code I would like a list or a column that says either "True" or "False" about whether the value exists.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are few tricks you can do.

Some ideas:

- you can try inner join, and then get the list of unique values, which appear in both dataframes. Then you can use the `isin` method in the smaller dataframe and that list to get your answer.

Dunno if this will work out of the box, but it would be something like:

```py
df_join = df_small.join(df_big, on='key', allow_duplicates=True)
common_samples = df_join[key].tolist()

df_small['is_in_df_big'] = df_small.key.isin(common_samples) 

# If it is something you gonna reuse a lot, but be worth doing
df_small = df_small.materialize('is_in_df_big') # to put it in memory otherwise it will be lazily recomputed each time you need it.
```

Similar idea: instead of doing join do something like:

```py
unique_samples = df_small.key.unique()
common_samples = df_big[df_big.key.isin(unique_samples)].key.unqiue()
df_small['is_in_df_big'] = df_small.key.isin(common_samples)
```

I dunno which one would be faster. I hope this at least will lead to some inspiration if not to the full solution.

Comment: I will give this a try, but I hope the same syntax is used in Vaex. That is the main problem I am having.

Comment: The examples above assume vaex dataframes etc... (I could have made a typo or mistake of course, but I wrote that example with vaex in mind)